# react: jotai, how to handle Promise inside atom()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jotai, tanstack

I was following a tutorial and was using the exact same code but because of a different dependency version, I get an error.

The Tutorial dependency version:

```
"jotai": "^1.9.0",
"jotai-tanstack-query": "^0.4.0",
```

My dependency version:

```
"jotai": "^2.1.0",
"jotai-tanstack-query": "^0.7.0",
```

The code:

```js
import { atom } from "jotai";
import { atomsWithQuery } from "jotai-tanstack-query";

export interface Pokemon {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  type: string[];
  hp: number;
  attack: number;
  defense: number;
  special_attack: number;
  special_defense: number;
  speed: number;
}

export const searchAtom = atom("");

const [allPokemon] = atomsWithQuery<Pokemon[]>(() => ({
  queryKey: ["pokemon"],
  queryFn: async () => {
    const res = await fetch("/pokemon.json");
    return res.json();
  }
}));

export const pokemonAtom = atom((get) => {
  const search = get(searchAtom).toLowerCase();
  const all = get(allPokemon);
  return all.filter((p) => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)); // Error
});
```

I get error: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Pokemon[] | Promise<Pokemon[]>'.
Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Promise<Pokemon[]>'.ts(2339)

It appears atomsWithQuery will also return a promise in the newer version. (Type of `allPokemon` in old version: `Pokemon[]`, new version `Pokemon[] | Promise<Pokemon[]>` ) How can I avoid/fix this error? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type tells you that `get(allPokemon)` might return an `array` or a `Promise` that resolves to an `array`. So what you should be able to do is `await` the response, then you can be sure that it's an `array` and not a promise. Then the type error should disappear, because it knows that the returned data is an `array` - then it knows that it has the `filter()` function.

```
export const pokemonAtom = atom(async (get) => {
  const search = get(searchAtom).toLowerCase();
  const all = await get(allPokemon);
  return all .filter((p) => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(search));
});
```

EDIT
Another way is to use the `useAtom` instead of `get` that will resolve it for you. Then you don't need to make your function asyncronious.

```
export const pokemonAtom = atom((get) => {
  const search = get(searchAtom).toLowerCase();
  const [all] = useAtom(allPokemon)
  return all.filter((p) => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)); // Error
});
```

Comment: thanks! I have no more errors. I was also wondering if it is possible to make the atom (pokemonAtom) not async since I now need to some of the frontend code...

Comment: @YukinosukeTakada Sure, look at the edited answer.

Comment: I tried the non asynchronous version but I got warning and it shows nothing.
Warning: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function.